# ImproperlyConfiguredError about app_name when using namespace in include()

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am currently trying out Django. I use the `namespace` argument in one of my `include()`s in urls.py. When I run the server and try to browse,
I get this error.

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

These are my urls.py files:

```
#project/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace='reviews')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

and

```
#app/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /
    url(r'^$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    # ex: /review/5/
    url(r'^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    # ex: /wine/
    url(r'^wine$', views.wine_list, name='wine_list'),
    # ex: /wine/5/
    url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.wine_detail, name='wine_detail'),
]
```

What do I pass the `app_name` as stated in the error message?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Check the docs for include [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#include).

What you've done is not an acceptable way of passing parameters to include. You could do:

```
url(r'^reviews/', include(('reviews.urls', 'reviews'), namespace='reviews')),
```

Comment: Just tried this out and got another error...url(r'^reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace='reviews', app_name='reviews')),
TypeError: include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app_name'

Comment: Extremely sorry. That was supposed to be used with modules not patterns. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: This solution was helpful for me as well. I was following the tutorial from https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_02.html and there is an instruction to do: urlpatterns = [
    # OAuth 2 endpoints:
    url(r'^o/', include(oauth2_endpoint_views, namespace="oauth2_provider")),
    url(r'^api/hello', ApiEndpoint.as_view()),  # an example resource endpoint
]. This generates the same error as you mentioned.

Comment: The tuple-syntax did not work for me, it only worked when I changed (my version of) `reviews.url` to have an `app_name` variable in `django 2.1`.

Comment: What is the use case for this? I have a lot of included urls in my project and all with the same pattern: `path("the_app/", include(("app.urls", <name>), namespace=<the same name>))` and it's quite annoying.

Answer (score 127):

### **Django 1.11+, 2.0+**

You should set the app_name in the urls file you are including

```
# reviews/urls.py  <-- i.e. in your app's urls.py

app_name = 'reviews'
```

Then you can include it the way you are doing it.

Also, it might be worth noting what Django docs say here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#include :

> Deprecated since version 1.9: Support for the app_name argument is
>   deprecated and will be removed in Django 2.0. Specify the app_name as
>   explained in URL namespaces and included URLconfs instead.

( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#namespaces-and-include )

Answer (score 43):

Django 2.0 you should specify **app_name** in your **urls.py**, is not necessary to specify app_name argument on include.

**Main Url file.**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('apps.main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Included Url.**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Then use use in template as

```
<a href="{% url main_app:index' %}"> link </a>
```

More details: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28691 
[Django 2.0 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs)

Comment: i wonder, what is the use of app_name = "main" is? and how django uses this variable

Answer (score 4):

I included a library not (fully) django 2.1 compatible yet (django_auth_pro_saml2). Hence I create a second file `saml_urls.py`:

```py
from django_saml2_pro_auth.urls import urlpatterns

app_name = 'saml'
```

Such that I could include the urls as:

```py
from django.urls import include, re_path as url

urlpatterns = [
    ..., url(r'', include('your_app.saml_urls', namespace='saml')), ...
]
```

Hacky, but it worked for me, whereas the `url(r'^reviews/', include(('reviews.urls', 'reviews'), namespace='reviews'))` did not.

Answer (score 2):

I am also face the same error in **Django 2.2** and i solve it this way

**urls.py file**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('publisher-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='publisher-polls')),
]
```

**polls/urls.py file**

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

example use of namespace in calss based view method

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse
    return reverse('polls.index', args=[str(self.id)])
```

example use of namespace in templates

```
{% url 'polls:index' %}
```

Here **polls:index** mean app_name[define in **polls/urls.py file**]:name[define in **polls/urls.py file** inside path function]

their official which is pretty good you can check for more info [namespace_django_official_doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

Find unused files or directories in APP (reviews) directory, and detete this items !

Answer (score 0):

In project level urls.py

```
path('',include('appname.urls'), namespace= 'test')
```

Now in in your app level urls.py

```
app_name = 'test'
path('',views.index, name= 'home')
```

**Long story short is, You have to provide "app_name" in your app level urls and that same name should be your namespace name at project level url**