# Fake admin login page in Django

Tags: django, honeypot

I would like to have a fake login page, a.k.a honeypot, in Django. The real admin login page would have a different than standard URL, of course. I know that there is a django-admin-honeypot app, but it doesn't seem to work with Django 2+. Is there a quick way to create such a fake admin page which doesn't even have to have the IP logging capability? Alternatively, do you have a configuration of django-admin-honeypot that works with Django 2+? If yes, would you be able to share your URL file(s), please?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Best wishes,

Marcin

Comment: :D They fixed issues for Django 2 version 8 hours ago, here is the commit 

https://github.com/dmpayton/django-admin-honeypot/commit/cec1156c42adbe989e16f4813c4abf82769e73d7

Now you can use it with Django 2 also. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. It works for me without any modifications after installing the newest version of django-admin-honeypot. Hurrah :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, I **just** ran into the same issue with the django-admin-honeypot app and managed to get it to work with Django 2+ with a few modifications! :)

Because I was lazy, I simply edited the local django-admin-honeypot app files. This will break when the package is updated (but I guess it would be fixed by then).

1. Edit the following 2 files:

   - admin_honeypot/listeners.py line 7
   - admin_honeypot/views.py line 4

Those go from being

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

to

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

2. Instead of what is stated in the admin_honeypot docs, use the following for the urlpattern.

This is similar to ['Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/specifying-a-namespace-in-include-without-providing-an-app-name)

Instead of

```
url(r'^admin/', include('admin_honeypot.urls', namespace='admin_honeypot')),
```

use

```
url(r'^admin/', include(('admin_honeypot.urls', 'admin_honeypot'), namespace='admin_honeypot')),
```

Then run migrate.py and restart server etc etc.

That fixed it for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for those instructions. I'm sure that if I followed them, I would be able to resolve my issue. However, a newer version of django-admin-honeypot module has been released, a few days after asking my question here, and everything works as expected.