# Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name ' django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url #22.JUN.2018 #25.Jun.2018
from django.contrib import admin

#from bookmark.views import BookmarkLV, BookmarkDV

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^bookmark/',include('bookmark.urls', namespace='bookmark')),
        url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
```

I need you guys help!!!
This is my code. And i have a error....please help me....

> 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app\_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/specifying-a-namespace-in-include-without-providing-an-app-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a variable called `app_name` in the included `urls.py` module.

For example if you have this include in your project urls.py:

`url(r'^bookmark/',include('bookmark.urls', namespace='bookmark'))`

you have to add a variable:

`app_name = 'bookmark'`

just before the definition of `urlpatterns` variable in bookmark/urls.py file.

Comment: I didn't know where you i write app_name=blog. 
Now, i solved the problem. Thanks!!

Solution is going into the app file ex)/blog/urls.py
and then write app_name='blog'

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know where you i write app_name=blog.
However, i got it

Solution is going into the app file ex)/blog/urls.py 
and then write app_name='blog'

```
$ cd /home/꾸르잼/Django/mysite/bookmark
$ vi urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from bookmark.views import BookmarkLV, BookmarkDV

app_name='bookmark'

urlpatterns = [
# Class-based views
url(r'^$', BookmarkLV.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', BookmarkDV.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

If you have a same problem like me, hopefully you can solve it as watching this.
Have a good day