# 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '. Html files not in the application, but in project directory

Tags: python, django

I tries to do this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/build-data-product-django-user-management-du107uyuh), but I have one problem. It is caused another version Django. I have seen many similar topics on the forum but I was not able match them to my situation.

When trying to start 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/' in files like those below, I can see the message 'NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/'.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'reviews')
Installed Middleware:
[]


Template error:
In template C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\aktualny_projekt-Podejscie_2\env\my_app\winerama\templates\base.html, error at line 21
   'auth' is not a registered namespace
   11 :         </div>
   12 :         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   13 :             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   14 :                 <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_list' %}">Wine list</a></li>
   15 :                 <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:review_list' %}">Home</a></li>
   16 :             </ul>
   17 :             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   18 :             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   19 :                 <li><a href="{% url 'auth:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
   20 :                 {% else %}
   21 :                 <li><a href=" {% url 'auth:login' %} ">Login</a></li>
   22 :                 {% endif %}
   23 :             </ul>
   24 :         </div>
   25 :     </nav>
   26 :     
   27 : 
   28 :     <h1>{% block title %}(no title){% endblock %}</h1>
   29 : 
   30 :     {% bootstrap_messages %}
   31 : 


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  75.                 extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]

During handling of the above exception ('auth'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  86.                     raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'auth' is not a registered namespace
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls',)) 

]
```

My settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ')g@^(l6+_uc*ckf%rj2i+89v^4^r3k!$l76husfgc74nk1#&g+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'reviews',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'winerama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'winerama.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My directory:

```
-templates
--base.html
--registration
---logged_out.html
---login.html
-winerama
--__init__.py
--settings.py
--urls.py
--wsgi
-reviews(all files from applications that work well)
```

Then I tried change my code in urls.py on:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'auth'

urlpatterns = [
    path('reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth'))

]
```

But CMD returns a message:

```
'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
```

I tried to change the code in login.html and urls.py but it also does not work good.

```
'<li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>' (login file)
'path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace=auth))' (urls file)
```

I think the error is caused the name of the application ('app_name = 'auth'). How i to give them the correct name(if my html files are not in the middle of any application)? Or how can I solve my mistake?

**EDIT (THE NEXT TEST 1)**

Well, below I wrote my steps:

1.) In my base.html I changed this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
```

and this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
```

2.) I'm going to my server, using the http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

3.)He returns me information:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'reviews')
Installed Middleware:
[]

Template error:
In template C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\aktualny_projekt-Podejscie_2\env\my_app\winerama\templates\base.html, error at line 8
   'auth' is not a registered namespace
   1 : {% load bootstrap3 %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% bootstrap_css %}
   4 : {% bootstrap_javascript %}
   5 : 
   6 : {% block bootstrap3_content %}
   7 : <div class="container">
   8 :     <na v class="navbar navbar -default">
   9 :         <div class="navbar-header">
   10 :             <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'reviews:review_list' %}">Winerama</a>
   11 :         </div>
   12 :         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   13 :             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   14 :                 <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_list' %}">Wine list</a></li>
   15 :                 <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:review_list' %}">Home</a></li>
   16 :             </ul>
   17 :             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   18 :             {% if user.is_authenticated %}


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  75.                 extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]

During handling of the above exception ('auth'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\tymot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  86.                     raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'auth' is not a registered namespace
```

**EDIT (THE NEXT TEST 2)**

Well, if shows me an error ('auth' is not a registered) after changes in html i try to add 'namespace='auth''.

1.1)I'm changing my urls.py file form this:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth' ))
]
```

1.2)Trying to start the server and CMD(Command Line) returns information

`'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '`.

1.3) Well i try add app_name:

```
app_name='django.contrib.auth' #or only 'auth'
urlpatterns = [
...
    path(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', ))
]
```

1.4) She still returns 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '. And here I do not know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried just using `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` without specifying a namespace? That's what I did when following the [MDN Django Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication). Scroll down to "Setting up your authentication views" to see what I mean.

Comment: Also have you looked at [this SO post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/specifying-a-namespace-in-include-without-providing-an-app-name) It seems to deal with the exact problem you're having.

Comment: When i try use 'path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))' and open my Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/, he returns information ''auth' is not a registered namespace'.

Yes, I saw this topic. Maybe I misunderstand it, but in that topic 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/specifying-a-namespace-in-include-without-providing-an-app-name' the person has a problem with this 'url(r'^reviews/', include(('reviews.urls', 'reviews'), namespace='reviews')),' I have a problem with 'path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls',))'

Comment: The important point is that to see my view accounts/login/ i only change my settings.py: TEMPLATES = [ ... 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], ... and my urls.py adding it: ' path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))' next I create template in the same directory where it is located manage.py and reviews. I do not have a special application for these addresses for example as to reviews app.

Comment: In your `base.html` template change `"{% url 'auth:logout' %}"` to `"{% url 'logout' %}"` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: i add changed,  result is above in the commentary. Maybe you have some idea how to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177189/discussion-between-mihai-chelaru-and-maddie-graham).

Comment: Okey, I have it! my error was not in the base file but in login.html. I changed only '<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" class="form">' and all is good. 
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: No problem. You can post the solution you got as an answer to your own question so others can see that it's resolved. You can also accept your own answer if you so choose.

Comment: how can I do this? I do not see this option next to yours comment?

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom. There should be a button that says 'Post your answer' and a big text box above it.