# I can not run server Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-2.0

Hello I'm having a problem when trying to run server from an Django 2.0 old project.

this is the error:

```
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.'
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from apps.sysgrub.views import LoginUser, LogoutUser

app_name = 'apps'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^alumno/', include ('apps.alumno.urls', namespace="alumno")),
    url(r'^grupo/', include ('apps.grupo.urls', namespace="grupo")),
    url(r'^maestro/', include ('apps.maestro.urls', namespace="maestro")),
    url(r'^rol/', include ('apps.rol.urls', namespace="rol")),
    url(r'^sysgrub/', include ('apps.sysgrub.urls', namespace="sysgrub")),
    url(r'^$', LoginUser),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutUser),
]
```

and my urls by app

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^index$', index),
url(r'^horarios$', horarios),
url(r'^listar$', Alumno_grupoList.as_view(), name='alumno_listar'),
url(r'^agregar$', AlumnoCreate.as_view(), name='add_student'),

]
```

thank you so much for your help greetings.

Comment: You must have an `app_name` variable in each of the modules you include that way. (`apps.alumno.urls` etc.) You don't need app_name in the root urls.py.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app\_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/specifying-a-namespace-in-include-without-providing-an-app-name)

Comment: Thank you that was the problem.
Have an excellent day.

Answer (score 0):

The error describes the resolution please remove app name from the urls.py as below

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^alumno/', include ('alumno.urls', namespace="alumno")),
url(r'^grupo/', include ('grupo.urls', namespace="grupo")),
]
```