# Django include app urls in my main url.py

Tags: python, django

I have a django site with 3 application.
in my urls.py i try to include the specific app's url in this fashion:

```
url(r'^oferty/', include('oferty.urls', namespace='oferty')),
```

but when i start or migrate my app i get this error:

> ../site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
>       'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

How can i include  apps urls in my main url.py file?
I use django 2.2

so many thanks in advance

Comment: Check the answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/impropyconfigurederror-about-app-name-when-using-namespace-in-include

Comment: one possible solution is, to remove namespace and then run migrations

Answer (score 0):

You need to define variable `app_name` in your file: `oferty/urls.py`

see example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#id5

or simply remove `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

**in my_app**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.home, name="home"),

]
```

**in main project urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),  # Include myapp URLs


]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).