# Path error in django rest framework : Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

In my django rest framework app I have `Urls.py` as follows:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .shipper import*
from .views import *


urlpatterns = [path('shipper/',
                    include(path('shipperitems/', MasterItemsList.as_view()),
                            path('shippercreateapi/', shipperCreateAPIView.as_view()),)),

               ]
```

When I try to run the app it gives me the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in
>   include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the
>   app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple
>   containing t he list of patterns and app_name instead.

what should I do to resolve this ?

Comment: Encounter the same problem when learning `djangorestframework`. Seems the tutorial from rest_framework is outdated. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#urls

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [**`include(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#include) function in the wrong way. **`include(...)`** usually takes the module which contains url-patterns. So change your code as below,

```
#root urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('shipper/', include('shipper.urls')),
]
```

and

```
#/shipper/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('shipperitems/', MasterItemsList.as_view()),
    path('shippercreateapi/', shipperCreateAPIView.as_view()),)),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for include [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#include). You should pass paramters to include like this

```
url(r'^reviews/', include('app_name.urls', 'app_name'), namespace='app_name')),
```

([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/impropyconfigurederror-about-app-name-when-using-namespace-in-include))