# Translating code from Django version 1.9 to version 2.0

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to get started with Django. But the book am using is using Django version <1.9 while the current version is >2.0

The problem am facing right now is this code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace = learning_logs'))
]
```

I have looked around and this is what I have written

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('learning_logs/', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace = 'learning_logs')),
]
```

but when I run the server I get the error:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Any help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImproperlyConfiguredError about app\_name when using namespace in include()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608894/improperlyconfigurederror-about-app-name-when-using-namespace-in-include)

Answer (score 0):

In the `learning/urls.py` you need to set `app_name = 'learning_logs`. Not in the module that includes those urls.

BTW, you may want to run python with `-Wd` switch so that you get deprecation warnings sooner and you'll be able to maintain your code more easily.

Comment: Thanks. And can you give sample code of how to run the `-Wd`. Am using windows. Thanks for the help. I will try it out and see what happens

Comment: I guess it would be something similar. Maybe try `py -Wd manage.py runserver`.

BTW, if I solved your problem, please mark this answer so that everyonen else knows it's a proper solution.